# How to send an C Array to a function which waits for a printf format in one line?

Tags: arrays, c, function, type-conversion

I have an array containing hex values like this: d3 8a f0 21 1e 1f e7 c3 a1 a4 47.
This array is part of a struct and I want to send it to another function which waits for a printf like statement

```
send_array(arg1, arg2, "%s\n", array);
```

The problem here is that I cannot provide this array for the send_array function with a for loop iterating over the array as usual.

Usually this function is used by sending a printf statement to it:

```
const char *message;
message = "This is a demo message";    
send_array(arg1, arg2, "%s\n", message);
```

Which work perfectly fine. I cannot modify the function to handle arrays in another way.
Is there a way to bring the content from the array into the same form as the "message" in the second snippet?

I am not that familiar with C language because I am used to higher level languages.

Hope someone can help me.

Comment: So: 1. Print the array into a temporary string. 2. Send that string. (3. free memory ;) `an array containing hex values` Any array can contain values. "Hex" is just a _way of representing_ values in base 16. Is it an array of `int`s? Of `char`s? Of `long ints`? Please post the code that has the array declaration and how is the array filled with values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `sprintf()` your array to a char buffer, then send that buffer.

```
int array[] = {0xd3, 0x8a, 0xf0, 0x21, 0x1e, 0x1f, 0xe7, 0xc3, 0xa1, 0xa4, 0x47};
char buffer[1000]; // large enough
char *b = buffer + sprintf(buffer, "%02x", array[0]);
for (unsigned i = 1; i < sizeof array / sizeof *array; i++) {
    b += sprintf(b, " %02x", array[i]);
}
send_array(arg1, arg2, "%s\n", buffer);
```

See code [running on ideone](https://ideone.com/YSUrj5)

Comment: Note: *if you like to live on the edge,* you may want to `malloc()` and `realloc()` (and `free()`) the buffer so that it is never larger than necessary. Also you may prefer `snprintf()` to ensure you never cause buffer overflow.

Comment: Thank you. That solved my issue. I need only to implement additional memory management now as in the comment above.